# Can't figure out preg_replace string

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace

I can't figure out how to use the preg_replace function for the following string: ,$

Here is what I am using now:

```
$camp_ANS_STAT_SQL = preg_replace(",$", "", $camp_ANS_STAT_SQL);
```

I've looked around and tried to use backslashes and forward slashes but can't seem to find the right combination.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you're looking to replace a fixed string, `str_replace` is probably a better fit.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that `$` is a special character meaning "end of the string".  `,$` is searching for a `,` followed by the end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no regular expressions needed

```
$camp_ANS_STAT_SQL = str_replace(",$", "", $camp_ANS_STAT_SQL);
```

[str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)